# double expectation

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, stochastic-analysis

I wanted to ask if

$\mathbb{E}\bigl[\mathsf{E}(X)\bigl]=\mathbb{E}\bigl[X\bigl]$?

$\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathsf{E}$ are two expectations on different spaces.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what you mean by "on different spaces", but whatever it means, $E(X)$ is a real number, so $\mathbb E[E(X)]=E(X)$. So if your equality is true, then $E(X)=\mathbb E[X]$, so $E$ and $\mathbb E$ are the same operators, which seems to contradict whatever you mean by "$\mathbb E$ and $E$ are expectations on different spaces".